# Ошибка при отправке email с вложенным файлом

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

Моему приложению требуется функция отправки вложенных файлов из внешнего хранилища по email при помощи сторонних приложений по типу GMail. Однако при попытке сделать это выбрасывается исключение, которое не проясняет ситуацию.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    File simpleFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        simpleFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "simple_file.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            if (!simpleFile.exists()) {
                simpleFile.createNewFile();
            }

            fos = new FileOutputStream(simpleFile);
            fos.write("Some simple text".getBytes());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendEmail(View view) {
        Intent emailIntent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"xxxxxxx@gmail.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Some subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some text");

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(simpleFile);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email"));
    }
}
```

Ошибка возникает при срабатывании startActivity() в последней строчке.Помогите разобраться где кроется проблема.

Stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.checksendemail, PID: 13328
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.checksendemail/files/simple_file.txt exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1958)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2356)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:941)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9735)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9741)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9720)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1609)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
        at com.example.checksendemail.MainActivity.sendEmail(MainActivity.java:59)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Какая ошибка появляется?

Comment: @ArtyMorris вот строка из стактрейса: Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.checksendemail/files/simple_file.txt exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri() Подозреваю, что проблема где-то здесь. Но файл существует, поэтому не понятно, почему возникает подобное.

Comment: @ArtyMorris добавил в вопрос stacktrace

Comment: Разрешение на чтение, разрешение на интернет есть конечно в манифесте?

Comment: просто так путь в Intent нельзя помещать - ищи по коду ошибки

Comment: @ArtyMorris Как я понимаю, разрешение на чтение и интернет для моего приложения не требуется, так как оно делится лишь адресом на файл, а точнее объектом Uri с почтовым клиентом, который уже осуществляет отправку файла. Но на всякий случай я добавил эти разрешения в свое приложение. Но код по-прежнему не работает.

Comment: @Style-7 я передаю в Intent через putExtra() объект Uri. Это пример из документации. Проблема, как мне кажется, именно в объекте Uri. Я как-то его не правильно получаю.

Comment: я все это понял, но вы не поняли Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed